# Connecting to Teradata with Perl and undefined symbol: DBCHINI

Tags: perl, teradata

i am having issues trying to get perl to connect to Teradata. I have installed the Teradata DBD from CPAN as well as the teradata utilities required. however when i attempt to run a perl script i get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Teradata     /Cli/Cli.so: undefined symbol: DBCHINI
```

thinking that this was an issue with paths and what appears to be an issue with Teradata drivers looking in the 32 bit directories i updated the following paths:

```
export ODBCINI=/opt/teradata/client/14.00/odbc_64/odbc.ini 
export NLSPATH=/opt/teradata/client/14.00/odbc_64/msg/%N.cat 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/teradata/client/14.00/odbc_64/lib
export ODBC_HOME=/opt/teradata/client/14.00/odbc_64
```

however it did not resolve the issue. This is installed on a 64bit RHEL and i am using Perl v5.10.1